# How to show value from expression using EJS template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm using **EJS** template in **Nodejs** While printing value I have give below

```
  <%= JSON.stringify(users.emails)  %>

<h2> Hello, [{"value":"email@gmail.com"}]</h2>
```

While priting above line. Im getting this  [{"value":"email@gmail.com"}] from this all i want only email@gmail.com. Please help me out. Im getting response from facebook

```
{  
   "id":"11125897590",
   "displayName":"Name",
   "name":{  

   },
   "emails":[  
      {  
         "value":"emailbala@gmail.com"
      }
   ],
```

Comment: How do you pass data to you ejs file?

Comment: im getting responsive from facebook [Facebook api login]. i have shown above eg

Comment: Does your `<%= JSON.stringify(users.emails)  %>` correctly display `emailbala@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users.emails.length == 1 then:

```
<%= JSON.stringify(users.emails[0].value) %>
```

else:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i< users.emails.length; i++) { %>
    <%= JSON.stringify(users.emails[i].value) %>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Thanks you @shubham Beta and Mikhail